# Dividing HH:MM:SS by an integer

Tags: sql

I have a column, `Col1`, in the format `HH:MM:SS`, and an integer column `Col2`. I am trying to compute `Col1 / Col2` in the format `HH:MM:SS`. How can I do that?

I have tried using a convert function however the below query is ignoring the coverted values.
This is the Convert statement i used:

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR,Col1 / 1920) + ':' + RIGHT('00' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, Col1% 60), 2) AS Time,
```

I am using the following query to attempt to do the division

```
select (DateTime),(Col1),(Col2),
cast((Col2 - Col1 ) as int) 
    / case when [CallsHandledHalf] = 0 then null 
           else [Col2] end as [AVG]
from Table
where ValueID ='5122'
and DateTime between '11/01/12 05:00' and '11/30/12 16:30'
```

Comment: PS Col1 is the HH:MM:SS column in the table

Comment: I take it you're using SQL-Server?

Comment: What's the actual type of `Col1` (character, integer, time)?  Is the formatting an 'absolute' value (time-of-day), or a duration?  If absolute, what should happen when dealing with daylight savings time?  Also, please never use `BETWEEN` for date/time/timestamp, especially on SQL Server - see [this blog post](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common) for more details).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using sql server (2008 or higher), perhaps the following will clear things up for you:

```
-- starting with a string in HH:MM:SS format
declare @s varchar(8)
set @s = '12:00:00'

-- set a divisor
declare @d int
set @d = 2

-- divide the total seconds by the divisor
set @s = convert(time(0), dateadd(second, datediff(second, 0, @s) / @d, 0))

-- output the results   '06:00:00'
print @s
```

Note that you really should just keep time values in a `time` datatype to begin with, but there are implicit conversions allowed that will let you go back and forth like this.